# Python interactive plot widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, widget, ipywidgets

I would like to get these three plots into one, with dropdown tab. Any suggestions? I don't think it's possible to have a dropdown where you have different values?? The data is at the bottom.

```
Bets = pd.DataFrame(Season_group, columns=['BetW', 'BetR'])
Bets['NetNomR'] = Bets.BetR - 380
Bets['Return_pct'] = (Bets.BetR / 380 -1)
Bets['Return_pct'] = pd.Series(["{0:.2f}%".format(val * 100) for val in Bets['Return_pct']],index = Bets.index)


BetsPlot = pd.DataFrame(Season_group, columns=['BetW', 'BetR'])
BetsPlot['NetNomR'] = BetsPlot.BetR - 380
BetsPlot['Return_pct'] = (BetsPlot.BetR / 380 -1)

BetsBetW = BetsPlot.unstack().loc['09/10':'18/19', 'BetW']
BetsNetNomR = BetsPlot.unstack().loc['09/10':'18/19', 'NetNomR']
BetsReturn_pct = BetsPlot.unstack().loc['09/10':'18/19', 'Return_pct']


BetsBetW.plot.bar()
plt.title('Return')
BetsNetNomR.plot.bar()
plt.title('Net Return')
BetsReturn_pct.plot.bar()
plt.title('Net Percentage Return')
```

[image]

[The data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58EYx.png)

Comment: Please post data as a csv or text file instead of a png.